# cURL Error (58): unable to set private key file: '/var/www/work/xml/keys/client.pem' type PEM

Tags: php, ssl, curl, openssl, libcurl

I am getting this error, while connecting to a server using private and public keys.

**cURL Error (58): unable to set private key file: '/var/www/work/xml/keys/client.pem' type PEM**

My private keys contain both key and certificate.   It has also password.

My current code is here:

```
    $url="https://example.website.com";

    $pemfile = "/var/www/work/xml/keys/server.pem";
    $keyfile = "/var/www/work/xml/keys/client.pem";

    $requestXml = file_get_contents("net.xml");

    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, 1.1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 443); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_HTTPS);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 0); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $pemfile); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE, 'PEM'); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, 'PASSWORD'); 


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, $keyfile); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD, "PASSWORD");


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestXml);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);
    $curl_error = curl_error($ch);

    if ($curl_errno > 0) 
    {
        echo "cURL Error ($curl_errno): $curl_error\n";
    }
    else 
    {
        header("Content-Type: text/xml");
        print_r($data);
    }

    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: I think that you private key file should only contain the private key. The cert file should contain your public certificate + any chained certificates.

Comment: I did that too but no impact on output :(

Comment: IDK, but seems to me like you may be using the wrong files.., is *server.pem* the root CA? Seems like `$pemfile` should be something like *.../client.pem* and `$keyfile` should be something like *.../client.key*.

Comment: post the VERBOSE log..

Comment: also post the output of ```<?php var_dump(shell_exec("namei -l /var/www/work/xml/keys/client.pem"));```

Answer (score 1):

it appears your script can not access the `$keyfile` file correctly. you may want to double-check that your script (or process) has the correct privileges, or modify the file permissions.

Comment: I have cross check it already.  The permissions are 777 for all files